# Wireguard can't access other peer's network from one peer only

Tags: wireguard

I setup the wireguard tunel between two houses. One house has a FritzBox (managed router) with 192.168.168.0/24 network, and the other one runs Linux machine behind router on 192.168.1.0/24 network. I've created the wireguard network 10.0.0.0/24 and I can do from my FritzBox:

```
➜  ~ traceroute 192.168.1.1
traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.168.1 (192.168.168.1)  10.830 ms  3.866 ms  3.949 ms
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  50.881 ms  49.701 ms  54.306 ms
 3  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  50.524 ms  49.579 ms  52.070 ms
```

And I can also access e.g. webpage that's being served from 192.168.1.1.

However, on the other side I have terrible issues. For example:

```
root@thinkpad:/etc/wireguard# tracepath 192.168.168.1
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1200
 1:  10.0.0.4                                             46.802ms reached
 1:  10.0.0.4                                             44.978ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1200 hops 1 back 1
root@thinkpad:/etc/wireguard# tracepath 192.168.168.50
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1200
 1:  10.0.0.4                                             47.135ms
 1:  10.0.0.4                                             46.351ms
 2:  10.0.0.4                                             48.407ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1200 hops 2 back 2
```

and I can't access anything on the network.

```
root@thinkpad:/etc/wireguard# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

and here's the wireguard config on the broken side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
MTU=1200
ListenPort = 47115
PrivateKey = 
PostUp = iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -w -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE
[Peer]
PublicKey =
PresharedKey =
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24, 192.168.168.0/24
```

and this is the good side:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.4/24
PrivateKey = 

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = my-host.com:47115
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening - why can't it penetrate, but keeps hitting the 10.0.0.4.

Comment: You probably need MASQUERADING on the good side too (is this a Site-to-Site setup?)